# Как настроить MathJS под себя?

Tags: javascript, математика

Скачал библиотеку MathJS, теперь появилась проблема - хочу настроить под себя. Написал небольшой парсер, используя math.parse(). Вроде все получается, но мне нужно убрать/добавить операторы. Как убрать ясно: нашел строку с exports.operators, убрал лишнее.
А как добавить оператор? А то я заметил - некоторые операторы стоят после числа, некоторые перед, некоторые между. И не получается добавить двух-символьные операторы типа || и &&.